# Why does polynomial division carry from $\Bbb Z[x]$ to $\Bbb Q[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation

I'm reading Artin's Algebra. In 11.3.24, it is stated

> Let $f$ be a monic integer polynomial, and let $g$ be another integer polynomial. If $f$ divides $g$ in $\Bbb Q[x]$, then $f$ divides $g$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

The proof being

> Since $f$ is monic, we can do division with remainder in $\Bbb Z[x]$: $g = f q + r$. This equation remains true in the ring $\Bbb Q[x]$, and division with remainder in $\Bbb Q[x]$ gives the same result. In $\Bbb Q[x]$, $f $ divides $g$. Therefore $r = 0$, and $f$ divides $g$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

I can't understand why division in $\Bbb Q[x]$ gives the same result.

Answer (score 3):

As I was writing the question I realized why it must be true.

It hinges on $f$ being monic. So while doing long division, the leading coefficient of $q$ must be the same as the leading coefficient of $g$ (because the leading coefficient of $f$ is $1$), and from then the long division gives the exact same result at every step, thus giving identical $q$ and $r$ in both rings.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242). It is best to delete this Q&A since we already have too many instances of it here.